# Implement dynamic sidebar filters laravel

Tags: javascript, mysql, laravel

I am trying to build a ad website and stuck at implementing the side filters on the sidebar navigation that are displayed based on the selected category.

1 : https://www.pigiame.co.ke/cars

2 : https://www.pigiame.co.ke/mobile-phones

Notice the different filters that appear on the sidebar based on the category selected on the main menu. Need help with showing the different filters.

Comment: each category have options which you fill when writing an ad, you just pull the options that are related to the category you're viewing & add these as filters.

Comment: @ahmad, thats true each ad should have option , which in some cases are drop down , others input fields, how exactly do you show those in the front end if they are stored in the db?

Comment: @ahmed, and also how you pull the different dynamic fields when posting the ads based off the category selected.

Comment: It's all about data structure, think about what about/features you want to build then design your database/tables around that idea to make your work easier.

Comment: @ahmad, I want to implement a web application similar to the link shared earlier, so maybe you can suggest a simple database design especially for the filters

Answer (score 0):

The simplest form would be something like the following

Assuming you have a product_features tables, your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`feature`) `feature_name` FROM `product_features` `pf`
INNER JOIN `products` `p` ON `p`.`id` = `pf`.`product_id`
WHERE `p`.`category_id` = ?
```

this should give you all the features for a category, you can then make your menu based on your category_id which you pass to the menu